# categorize an array and get the first and the last value based on its group and its order

Tags: php, arrays

i have json response that i decode :

```
$myJSON = '[
  {"group": "a", "num":1 },
  {"group": "a", "num":2 },
  {"group": "a", "num":3 },
  {"group": "b", "num":4 },
  {"group": "b", "num":5 },
  {"group": "c", "num":6 },
  {"group": "d", "num":7 },
  {"group": "-", "num":8 },
  {"group": "d", "num":9 },
  {"group": "d", "num":10 }
]';

$data = (json_decode($myJSON));
```

i want an ouptut that return only first array and last array grouped by its value, something like :

```
{
    "a": [
      {
        "first": 1,
        "last": 3,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
      }
    ],
    "b": [
      {
        "first": 4,
        "last": 5,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
      }
    ],
    "c": [
      {
        "first": 6,
        "last": 6,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
      }
    ],
    "d": [
      {
        "first": 7,
        "last": 10,
        "first_blank": 8,
        "last_blank": 8
      }
    ]
}
```

i have try array reduce method to categorized its group, and then reset() method to get the first array, end() method to get last array but its output not like what i want, what confused me is in group 'd' the blank value part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want using `array_reduce`. The callback function checks the `group` value from the current object, and if a different letter, creates a new group in the output; otherwise, as long as the `group` is not `-`, it updates the `last` value of the current group. If the `group` value is `-`, then `first_blank` and `last_blank` are updated as needed:

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function ($c, $v) {
    $group = $v->group;
    $num = $v->num;
    if ($group == '-') {
        // blank value
        $keys = array_keys($c);
        $currentgroup = end($keys);
        if ($c[$currentgroup]['first_blank'] == '') {
            $c[$currentgroup]['first_blank'] = $num;
        }
        $c[$currentgroup]['last_blank'] = $num;
    }
    else {
        if (!isset($c[$group])) {
            $c[$group] = array('first' => $num, 'last' => $num, 'first_blank' => '', 'last_blank' => '');
        }
        else {
            $c[$group]['last'] = $num;
        }
    }
    return $c;
}, []);

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": {
        "first": 1,
        "last": 3,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
    },
    "b": {
        "first": 4,
        "last": 5,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
    },
    "c": {
        "first": 6,
        "last": 6,
        "first_blank": "",
        "last_blank": ""
    },
    "d": {
        "first": 7,
        "last": 10,
        "first_blank": 8,
        "last_blank": 8
    }
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tUH3o)

Comment: that's insane !! thanks by the way and happy new years